# Chrome extension: Communication between content script and background.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am new to Chrome extensions. I am trying to communicate between the content script and the *background.html* page. The *background.html* sends a request, "*hello*", to the content script and the content script should respond back with "*hello background*" alert. But it's just not happening. My *background.html* code is:

```
function testRequest() {        
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"});
    });    
}
```

*content.js* code:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "hello")
        alert("hello background");
    }
);
```

*popup.html* code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="sendMessage" onclick="testRequest()" />
        </form>    
    </body>
</html>
```

*manifest.json*:

```
{
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "notifications",
        "contextMenus"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "name": "FirstExtension",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`sendRequest`/`onRequest` is replaced with `sendMessage`/`onMessage` in Chrome 20. `*Message` is not just an alias for `*Request`, it's a different API.

If you want to support Chrome <20 (many Ubuntu users are still at Chromium 18, because the PPA is not updated), use `onRequest` and `sendRequest`. Otherwise, use the `*Message` methods.

---

Another problem is that your function is located in the background page, and the call is made in the pop-up. These are different scopes, if you want to call a background page method from the popup, use [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage):

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().testRequest();
```

Final note: You're using manifest version 1 and inline event handlers. This practice is deprecated, for more information, see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html.

Comment: @user975234 Tge [documentation on `onMessage`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage) does not match the actual situation, by the way. For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11811936.