# Background page not storing data in its localStorage in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Port error while changing chrome extension from manifest v1 to v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913575/port-error-while-changing-chrome-extension-from-manifest-v1-to-v2)

I am creating a chrome extension where I store data in localStorage of the background page.
I am taking the data from a content script and sending it to background page via message passing, I don't know why, but the data is not getting stored.

Here is the code snippet I have written.

background.html:

```
<script>
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
localStorage.setItem(request.username,request.password);
sendResponse(null);
});
</script>
```

content-script:

```
document.getElementById('login_form').addEventListener('submit',
                                                        function(){
                                                            _Userid = document.getElementById('email').value;
                                                            _UserPass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
                                                           chrome.extension.sendRequest({username: _Userid, password: _UserPass}, function(response) {
                                                                                                                                                           alert('done') });

   },false);
```

Please Note that Message passing is working fine, as I do get the response back from , background page and an alert box also appears.

Comment: Are there any errors on console when you debug the background page? Are you sure `_Userid` is not empty? Are you sure you want to store these data as `"amogh":"sw0rdf1sh!"` (it doesn't seem normal to use variable as a key) and not as `"user":"amogh", "password":"sw0rdf1sh!"`? Do you know that localStorage on a background page can't be accessed directly from other pages? How do you check that data wasn't stored?

Comment: I went to backround.html from extensions page in chrome and checked resources.
I want username to be key and password to be its value.

Comment: I have cheked. _Userid and _UserPass are both proper strings.

Comment: I just checked, everything works fine If I use manifest version 1 and  if I use manifest version 2. Things dont work.

Comment: It's because sendRequest and onRequest is deprecated in manifest version 2. Try to use sendMessage and onMessage instead.

Comment: @KiL: Thanks a Lot ! Now everything becomes clearer. Unfortunately,
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html doesnt mention these changes.

Comment: @KIL **Wrong**. [`*Request` were superseded and deprecated in favour of `*Message` since **Chrome 20**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752341/chrome-extension-communication-between-content-script-and-background-html/11756188#11756188). There is **no relationship between manifest version and `*Request`->`*Message`**. Also, beware of incorrect documentation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11811936/938089

Comment: @Rob W: My bad. I just noticed that Google deprecated *Request in their documents. I didn't know the fact that they was superseded in Chrome 20. Thank you for correcting me!