# how do i learn chrome.extension.sendRequest method?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have tried to browse through the extension APIs and have searched google. I can find the information available for chrome.extension.sendMessage but its hard to find anything for the chrome.extension.sendRequest method.

Please help for the best tutorial to Chrome Extensions as atleast here Google is not helping me much :(

Comment: `chrome.extension.sendRequest` was superseded by `chrome.extension.sendMessage` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11756188. Can you post your *current* code, and explain what you don't understand about it? Do you understand the meaning of the terms "asynchronous" and "event"?

Comment: Ya I know about asynchronous and call back functions and event, was getting really confused about the sendRequest method. Thanks for the update. 

I have not written anything was reading SpeakSelection code in google chrome extension API's, its a bit tough to understand some parts. 

What advice do you give for learning google chrome extension API's and all considering that I have exposure to Javascript and general HTML.

Comment: I suggest [Getting started](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) and [Overview](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html). Then, learn the core APIs (which are used quite often): [`chrome.extension`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html) and [`chrome.tabs`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html). Make sure that you also know how to deal with [Background pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) and [Content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: Many useful pages are referred through the [Developer guide](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html), including [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) which may answer your question.

Comment: Stop using comments as answers!

Answer (score 2):

It is deprecated.

use sendMessage:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage